# Build a Famo.us iOS app

Tags: famo.us

I have followed the [Famo.us](https://famo.us/university) tutorial thinking that I would be able to get an iOS app at the end of it. So far, I can build browser apps using the Famo.us JavaScript API, but I cannot get any documentation explaining how to convert my browser app into an iOS app.

How can I build an iOS app from a Famo.us browser app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the main [famo.us](https://famo.us) page, we can see the definition of what famo.us is and what we can do with it.

> Famo.us is a free, open source JavaScript framework that helps you
>   create smooth, complex UIs for any screen.
>
> Famo.us is the only JavaScript framework that includes an open source
>   3D layout engine fully integrated with a 3D physics animation engine
>   that can render to DOM, Canvas, or WebGL.

Theres no official documentation from famo.us about how to embed a webapp/mobile-site on a iOS app.

Check the [Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/) or [Phonegap](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_index.md.html) frameworks, with them you can embed the famo.us webapp into a native app.